# Next.js application with IIS Reverse Proxy accesses public assets on root path

Tags: next.js, iis

I made a sample Next.js application and am trying to create a production environment that runs the application with Windows Server.

The first approach was using IIS Node, but we have IIS 10 and could not downgrade to version 7 or 8.

The second approach was using an IIS Rewrite and Reverse Proxy to point a specific URL to the Next.js application.

So I started the Next App on localhost:4001 and created an IIS site. In that site, an application with the name "test" was configured. I set up the URL Rewrite as a Reverse Proxy, so now:

`domain/test` points to `localhost:4001`

(I want to keep it this way because in the future I want to create additional apps on sub-routes like `domain/app2` or something.)

The application is accessible on `domain/test`, and the HTML loads in, but assets are throwing a 404 error.

I managed to find out that Next.js is requesting every asset on `domain/`, but they are accessible on the `domain/test/` path.

Next.js has two configuration options: `basePath` and `assetPrefix`.

If I change `basePath` to `"/test"`, then the problem is not solved because everything just shifts with one more `/test`, so the app is now accessible on `domain/test/test`, but the assets are still inaccessible because now they are located on `domain/test/test/_next...` but requested on `domain/test/_next...` by the application. I'm not even talking about the assets in the public folder, which are still requested on the root domain.

The other option is `assetPrefix`. After changing `assetPrefix` to `"/test"`, the application is accessible on `domain/test`, and the basic assets (CSS, JS) are loaded in beautifully, but the assets in the public folder are still requested on the root of the domain.

Changing everything to `/test/(public asset name)` solves the issue in production, but it ruins everything in development. Is there any way to configure Next.js to access assets in the public folder where the `assetPrefix` is set, maybe in build time, without introducing the need to run a function every time a request comes in or manually changing every path?

I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint with this, so I can know which way to look around. I'm out of ideas.

The Application should work in a way, that the assets in the public folder should be requested on the `domain/test` path, without manually changing every url.

Comment: You will find HttpPlatformHandler a cleaner way to host Next.js apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs

Comment: This is a rather complicated process, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, microsoft engineer will help you to identify the problem.